# How to preload firestore data on app start up?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app that tracks the location of nearby coffee shops and allows users to view each shop's available products. I am using firestore to store all of the data for each product and showcasing this data to the user through a recyclerview + firestoreRecyclerAdapter. It works. However, the product data loads really slowly. Taking several seconds or even minutes to load the recyclerview. Even after the recycler is fully loaded, this problem persists.

Now, I think that it's because he reads from the database are overloading the main UI thread. So I have tried to perform these reads in an asyncTask, but I can't pull values from the asyncTask since it outputs data after the activity has requested it. Giving me an error.

I have tried decreasing the amount of data that is pulled from firestore. But that doesn't help either.

I am thinking about trying to load all of the product data from firestore to shared preferences, internal storage, or a package of some kind while the app is starting up. That way requests don't need to be sent to the server. In this way, the server can serve as a way to update this data rather than continuously attempt to retrieve it.

However, I am lost on how to do this. How can a load firestore data say a custom object, save that list of custom objects to an array, then provide some way for this data to be loaded in and accessed later?

Comment: Reads from Firestore do not occur on the main thread.  Without seeing your code and understanding what exactly is in your database, it's impossible to tell if Firestore reads are causing a delay.  We can't tell if maybe you're reading 1000 giant documents at startup.

Comment: I only have 10 documents inside the database. Loading smaller portions of this list loads rather quickly. But anymore than 5 can take a while. I am new to android studio (coming from python and unity). So this is still very new and frustrating.

Comment: I will post an example of my code later on for better inspection. Meanwhile, i will be reading up on Olehcoding's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore database has offline persistence enabled for mobile platforms by default. It means it saves loaded data and what you have queried in cache. Try to read this 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline .
Also do not try to save your data in shared preferences, it is designed to contain small chunks of data stored in Key/Value pair.
To be more specific, I think the performance problem is in your code.

I would suggest few things: move realization of your code to your activity/fragment - from your adapter.(Just create interfaces with which you can operate to open new activity/fragment/onClick something etc with your items in adapter)

I also highly suggest to use Livedata + ViewModel, it helped me a lot to deal with performance problems. Check out this blog https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html . It helped me to understand the principles and implement it in my code. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you sooo much Olehcoding! This has been racking my brain for 2 weeks now. I'll take your advice to heart and try my best to implement it. I will also post an example of my code just in case.

Comment: sure, no problem. If you have any problem, you can write here or message me. 
If the answer helped you, mark it as correct. Good luck big man!